# Add percentage sign in dataframe column

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and can't quite understand how to add a percentage sign in just one column of my dataframe. I want to make the 'Engagement' column values have all percentage signs when I load the dataframe.
The Engagement column is made from Likes divided by vues * 100 (to make a percentage).

If someone was also able to help me how i could just formate every column to have the likes/vues * 100, it would also help

Here is my code :

```
Sujet <- sprintf("s_%d", 1:16)

Titre <- c("Coffee cake cookies", "Poutine baloney", "Polite Boy","Infinity water glitch", "Garlic  butter steak bites", "Sun Conure", "Pizza in my room", "Parkour skills", "Supercars", "Brown monster", "Batch of pasta", "Police grappler", "F340", "Ceramic brakes", "GT3 Seat Solution", "Over Priced GT2RS" )

Likes <- c(150700, 11200, 3500000, 256700, 1400000, 791300, 439900, 382700, 45400, 1300000, 246200,   32200, 319000, 1892, 3413, 17400)

Vues <- c(1300000, 214500, 13500000, 11400000, 17100000, 6700000, 400000, 11300000, 203100, 18400000, 3000000, 1000000, 1800000, 12600, 23500, 213800)


Engagement <- c(150700 / 1300000, 11200 / 214500, 3500000 / 13500000, 256700 / 11400000, 1400000 /         17100000, 791300 / 6700000, 439900 / 4000000, 382700 / 11300000, 45400 / 203100, 1300000 / 18400000, 246200 / 3000000, 32200 / 1000000, 319000 / 1800000, 1892 / 12600, 3413 / 23500, 17400 / 213800)


classe_df <- data.frame(Sujet, Titre, Likes, Vues, Engagement)
```

Using the code has made it work in the data frame, but a new problem has occured. I used :

```
Engagement <- sprintf(fmt="%.1f%%", Likes/Vues*100)
```

But now, I can't use :

```
library(dplyr)
classe_df <- classe_df %>%
mutate(Lien_avec_médiane = ifelse(median(Engagement) > Engagement, "en- 
dessous", "au-dessus"))
```

The error code i get is that In argument: `Lien_avec_médiane =  ifelse(median(Engagement) > Engagement, "Below", "Above")`.
Caused by warning in `mean.default()`:
!argument is not numerical or logical : renvoi NA

Comment: Presumably you still want to be able to sort it numerically?  You can convert the number to a string and add a "%" if that's what you want, but it may instead be a display issue - how are you viewing/sharing/printing this information?  It may be easier to format it there.

Comment: no real need for `paste0`, use `sprintf(fmt="%.1f%%", ...)`

Comment: It can take a while to get used to, but I would encourage you _not_ to use percentages when working with data in R. Get used to working with _proportions_, and only convert to percentages if you are plotting or producing some other output for people who aren't used to proportions. This can always be done at the output stage; there is rarely a need to store percentages in a column.

Comment: @AllanCameron I need to calculate the likes divided per views in percentage, so I just wanted to be sure to do what was asked...

Comment: @Sam, you missed the point. Don't use `paste0`. Don't append the trailing `"%"`. Do _just_ `sprintf(fmt="%.1f%%", Likes/Vues*100)` to get the string. But really, take heed of Allan's comment about "keep as a number until the last step for plotting/rendering. The addition of `%` makes it completely not-a-number, breaking any further math-like-things you want to do on it. Don't convert to a percentage until you must.

Comment: @r2evans . I used Engagement <- sprintf(fmt="%.1f%%", Likes/Vues*100) at the end of my code (last step of the project), and it shows the values in percentages in the environment, but when I load my data frame, the values of the 'Engagement' column are not showing in percentages...

Comment: Welcome to R! If you've already defined `classe_df`, then any changes to `Engagement` after that have no effect on the data frame. To change the values _there_, use `classe_df$Engagement <- sprintf("%.1f%%", classe_df$Engagement)`.

Comment: Does defining it initially as `classe_df <- data.frame(Sujet, Titre, Likes, Vues, Engagement=sprintf("%.1f%%", 100*Engagement))` (after the raw code currently in your code block above) give you what you need? Or perhaps you'd prefer `classe_df <- data.frame(Sujet, Titre, Likes, Vues, Engagement=sprintf("%.1f%%", 100*Likes/Vues))`.

Comment: @r2evans I edited the post to make it more clear what the new problem is

Comment: I figured it out!! Thank you so much for your help with everything

Comment: That _warning_ is precisely why AllanCameron and I have guarded against converting from a number to a string too soon in your work. Again, I suggest you convert to percentage _as late as possible_, preferably just before rendering in a table or plot. Alternatively, there can be utility in having two columns: `Engagement` (a number) and `EngagementPct` (a string), so that when you need one or the other, you have both. It's just a technique. Good luck!